# Netid in ss output is confusing

Tags: tcp, udp

I'm on an Ubuntu 14.04 x64 machine. I have something running on port 51236 and I want to know whether it's TCP or UDP. So I ran `ss -an | grep 51236` and got the following output.

> tcp    ESTAB      0      0          *****:51236   *****:40047

(I substituted the asterisks for the real IP address)

To confirm, I ran `ss -ant | grep 51236` and got back nothing. But when I run `ss -anu | grep 51236`, I get the following.

> ESTAB      0      0             *****:51236      *****:40047

Now that the Netid column says it's TCP, why can't I find it using `-t` (TCP), but instead found it through `-u` (UDP)?

Comment: That's surprising. I can't find any relevant bug report. Does `netstat` exhibit the same behavior?

Comment: @TNW no, `netstat` is correct (Showing UDP)